# Number of distinct real roots of an integer polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I would like to bound the number of **distinct real** roots of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ depending on the height of the polynomial (or else another metrics) and the degree. Any related reference is welcome. I have thoroughly searched for an answer, but I haven't found anything about this question, even though I'm convinced that some results probably exist since the roots of integer polynomials have been quite studied.

Comment: The trivial bound is that the number of distinct real roots, if finite, is between 0 and the degree of the polynomial -- if that isn't good enough for your purposes, what is the criterion for a bound to be helpful?